# SupportMapFragment doesn't work on some android devices

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have an android application and in one activity i insert a google map using SupportMapFragment. The problem is that on my device (galaxy nexus with android 4.3) and in a galaxy s with android 2.3 it works good, while in other device (it doesn't matter which android version they have) it shows blank map with zoom controls. Api key is right (because on some device it works). Here is the code I used:

```
public class Mappa extends FragmentActivity{

GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mappa);

    if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
}
```

}

and here is the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/home_screen"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">
    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/menu_bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In androidmanifest file I set all permissions and api key as follow:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.mattialori.battagliadianghiari.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mattialori.battagliadianghiari.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxx" />
```

permissions are under manifest tag and api key is under application tag. Do I have to write something in activity tag? Here is what i wrote:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.mattialori.battagliadianghiari.Mappa"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: It does matter which devices. Do you know for sure they all have GooglePlayServices installed? You can check if they do and prompt the user accordingly to handle this kind of error.

Comment: if you don't use map api v2 in full screen (match_parent) it can create some glitch when changing activity or fragment transition.. whatever. Did you try using it simply full screen alone in an activity ?

Comment: I can't use it in full screen. I try to check if googleplayservices are installed

Comment: I also tried to use it in full screen but the result is the same, on my device it works, on others it doesn't. I also tried to generate the api key with a different google account but it doesn't work..